# Issue with folder permission in file server migration - Share Parmissions VS NTFS Permissions

Tags: permissions, network-share, file-permissions, ntfs, server-message-block

I am migrating a file server form 2003 to 2012 R2.

There are about 50TB of files with thousands of individual permissions.

I have successfully migrated the files to the new server, including their permissions which remain intact.

I am having problems with permissions.

Lets take the Accounts folder for example:
On the old file server, it is shared with the permission:
Everyone     Read
The NTFS security is set to:
Accounts      Full Control
Finance       Read & Write

This results in users being able to see the shared folder Accounts but not accesss it or view it's contents unless they are in the accounts or finance groups.

On the new 2012 server, i got to advanced sharing, add the permission for everyone to read, and create the share. I then check the NTFS permissions for the folder, they are still intact, Accounts, Finance, thats it.

The problem is, everyone can read every file in that folder. It appears the share permissions are taking precedence over the NTFS permissions.

The same thing happens on the 100+ shares on the new server, it is not feasible for me to manually re-do all the permissions.

Comment: I should add: When i try and view the permissions on the new server I get a blank screeen saying I must have read permissions to view the properties of this object. I then change the owner to that of the Domain Admins group I am a member of, and it still cannot see the permissions when I got back into the folder. Giving myself read permissions would not be acceptable on most folder, for example Legal, which even admins are not supposed to see. On the 2003 server this is not an issue.

Comment: Disable UAC on the server, so you won't need to force your permissions on every folder. As for you original question, we did the same migration, and it went perfect. Try redoing the permissions on one share, and see if it solves it. If it does, than consider scripting it.